# How to use Node.js promises for a function (CassandraDB driver when executing query)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cassandra, promise, datastax-enterprise

I am using client.stream() from Cassandra DB's driver to fetch large result sets using pages, then for each row result returned I am pushing it into an array defined at the top of my scope.

After the queries are finished, I want to return my array but It always returns 'undefined' and I am guessing its because fetching the queries takes a long time so Javascript proceeds with the return statement before the object is even populated.

For those not familiar with this driver: The client.stream is a function, and it takes a little while to get some data. I need to wait for this to finish before returning the object!

E.g

```
function foo() {
  var resultArray: [];
  var query = "select username from users where userRank = 3";
  client.stream(query, {prepare: true})
    .on('readable' function () {
      var row;
      while (row = this.read()) {
        resultArray.push(row.username); 
      }
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      return obj; // The object only exists in this scope but cant return from here
    });
}
```

When I call this `var returned = foo();` I get `undefined` as the return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `stream` API, you will need to create your own `Promise` instance and resolve it when the stream ended.

There is no point in buffering all the rows on your own and then return a `Promise`, the driver can do that for you. If you are not concerned about the memory consumption of having all those rows in memory, you can do:

```
// Disable paging
// NOTE: Memory consumption will depend on the amount of rows
// and the amount of concurrent requests
const options = { prepare: true, fetchSize: 0 };
const promise = client.execute(query, params, options);
```

See the documentation for more information: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/latest/features/paging/

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer, I was able to get `stream` to work wrapped in a Promise.

```js
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const results = [];

                return client
                    .stream(query, params, options)
                    .on('readable', function() {
                        // 'readable' is emitted as soon a row is received and parsed
                        let row;

                        while ((row = this.read())) {
                            results.push(row);
                        }
                    })
                    .on('end', function() {
                        // Stream ended, there aren't any more rows
                        return resolve(results);
                    })
                    .on('error', function(err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    });
            }),
```